# Как оставить разделитель в регулярном виражении как елемент списка?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x, строки

У меня есть строка `gs:vdd2[ebp+ebx*4]` мне нужно сделать такой список из элементов:  `['gs', ':', 'vdd2', '[', 'ebp', '+', 'ebx', '*', '4', ']' ]` 
я использую вот такое регулярное выражения `re.split('[:\\+\\*\\[\\],]',s)` чтоб вырезать все кроме разделителей. 
Как сделать чтоб еще добавлялись разделители?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import re
import string

pat = '([{}])'.format(re.escape(string.punctuation))

res = re.split(pat, s)
```

Результат:

```
In [62]: res
Out[62]: ['gs', ':', 'vdd2', '[', 'ebp', '+', 'ebx', '*', '4', ']', '']
```

или так:

```
In [63]: res = [x for x in re.split(pat, s) if x]

In [64]: res
Out[64]: ['gs', ':', 'vdd2', '[', 'ebp', '+', 'ebx', '*', '4', ']']
```